# Create owl file from csv file

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege4

Currently I am using Protege application to add classes, sub classes for the added classes and label for each subclass/class. I have many classes and I am really fed up adding many of these manually. I have got all of these classes, sub-classes and labels in a csv file. Each row contains these three things- class,sub-class and label separated by comma.

I would like to create OWL file with all these classes. Is there any way I could automate the process?

Comment: I'm using Open Refine with the RDF extension for that. Works very well. And now there is even dedicated LOD Refine but I had some issues with it. A colleague of mine wrote some macros and is using directly Excel.

Comment: @UdaySagar, try Cellfie plugin. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773889/add-multiple-individual-at-once-in-protege/44775905#44775905).

Comment: That's really cool @StanislavKralin Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use case seems pretty close to what a tool named Populous does. See its description [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3471341/)

> Populous presents users with a table based form in which columns are constrained to take values from particular ontologies. Populated tables are mapped to patterns that can then be used to automatically generate the ontology's content. These forms can be exported as spreadsheets, providing an interface that is much more familiar to many biologists.

The table/spreadsheet format is equivalent to CSV, so easy to convert. The project is Open Source, so easy to reuse the code to achieve your target.

See http://www.populous.org.uk/ for more details.