# Add multiple individual at once in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege

There is a wizard tab for Protege 3 to add multiple instances at once, but not for Protege 5. How may I add multiple instances to a class at once, for example copy & paste them from Excel to Protege?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use [Cellfie plugin](https://github.com/protegeproject/cellfie-plugin).

It is bundled with Protégé 5.2.0 and available from *Tools > Create axioms from Excel workbook...*

[image: Cellfie rule]

[image: Cellfie result]

Mapping language for transformation rules is described [here](https://github.com/protegeproject/mapping-master/wiki/MappingMasterDSL).
In fact, it is just a Manchester syntax dialect with spreadsheet references.