# How to create Sparql endopoint from data like .csv table?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology

I am quite new to Ontologies and Semantic Web. I started to create model ontology using Protégé for instance. My problem now is to create ontologies from data in table like `.csv` file. Suppose we have a table containing the name of cities, number of inhabitants and state of the city. How can I create a database that allows me to query in SPARQL? This an example of the table I have so far.

```
nameOfCities numberOfInhabitants State
 London          7,825,200         UK
 Paris           2,244,000         FR
 Rome            2,868,000         IT
```

I want to create an ontology where I have the classes `city`, `name`, `numberOfInhabitants` and `State`. While the relationships among the classes are the following:

`city hasName name`

`city hasNumberOfInhabitants numberOfInhabitants`

`city hasSpatialLevel State`

How can I create a SPARQL endpoint from a dataset like this?

Comment: If you want to use Protégé, then probably you could use the Cellfie plugin. See e. g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775905/7879193) for some details.

Comment: 1. Convert CSV to RDF 2. load TRDF into triple store