# Importing csv file instances to protege ontology

Tags: ontology, protege

I have created an ontology for a small project IN Protege, I have dataset related to the domain in csv file. How can I import all the individuals of classes to ontology in Protege, so that all the individuals are automatically added to the ontology?

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775905/7879193

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionaltiy like that in protege. What you will have to do is write some code using the [OWL API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi). Looking at the testcases for [DataFactory](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/impl/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/datafactory/OWLDataFactoryTestCase.java) will show you how you can add individuals with assertion axioms to an ontology using the OWL API.

Comment: Okay and from excel, can we export data from excel?

Comment: As @Stanislav mentioned. See Cellfie at https://github.com/protegeproject/cellfie-plugin.